# How can I update a UITableView from a dynamically downloaded text file?

Tags: ios, file, uitableview, download

I am filling a TableView from a text file. I want to enable the user to download an updated text file and replace the existing content of the TableView with the content of the downloaded file. I am able to download the file and replace the original file. If I close the application and open it again, it loads the updated file.

But the TableView doesn't change while the app is running. When I execute the method to load data from the file into the TableView, I can see, using NSLog, that the method is getting the original data from the file.

What am I doing incorrectly? How can I get the method to see the updated text file instead of the original text file?

Thanks.

```
@interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tableViewData;
@end

@implementation

/*
    When user presses button, IBAction method
    - downloads text file
    - saves the downloaded file, replacing the original text file
    - loads the text file into the TableView data (this is what doesn't work)
    - sends a reload message to the TableView
 */
- (IBAction)buttonUpdateTextFile:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSString *contentsOfTextFile = [self downloadTextFileFromURL:@"http://www.apple.com/index.html"];

    [self saveContentsOfTextFile:contentsOfTextFile toFile:@"tableViewData.txt"];
    [self loadDataFromFileWithFileName:@"tableViewData" fileExtension:@"txt"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSString *)downloadTextFileFromURL:(NSString *)textFileURLstring
{
    NSURL *textFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:textFileURLstring];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *contentsOfTextFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:textFileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    return contentsOfTextFile;
}

- (void)saveContentsOfTextFile:(NSString *)contentsOfTextFile toFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *pathName = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileNameWithPath = [pathName stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileNameWithPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileNameWithPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    [[contentsOfTextFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileNameWithPath atomically:NO];
}

- (void)loadDataFromFileWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName fileExtension:(NSString *)fileExtension
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName
                                                 ofType:fileExtension];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
    NSString *remainingText = [content mutableCopy];

    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSRange *substringRange;

    while (![remainingText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        substringRange = [remainingText rangeOfString:@"/n"];
        if (substringRange.location == NSNotFound) 
        {
            currentLine = remainingText;
            remainingText = @"";
        } else {
            substringRange.length = substringRange.location;
            substringRange.location = 0;
            currentLine = [[remainingText substringWithRange:substringRange] mutableCopy];

            //    - strip line from remainingText
            substringRange.location = substringRange.length + 1;
            substringRange.length = remainingText.length - substringRange.length - 1;
            remainingText = [[remainingText substringWithRange:substringRange] mutableCopy];
        }
        [data addObject:currentLine];
    }
    self.tableViewData = [data copy];
}
```

Comment: Are you downloading the file synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Synchronously, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
self.tableViewData = [data copy];
```

may be the problem.

I would make data a "private" property of the class.  Only init once and then manually add and remove objects to it.  Don't use copy.

Comment: The problem is, when I open the text file, after I've downloaded an updated version, the method doesn't see the new file, only the original file. So there's no data with which to update the TableView. The app doesn't know what to add or remove.